# Why do I get 'invalid literal for int()' when running my query?

Tags: django, django-queryset

In my show_reviews method in views.py, I am querying all reviews for a username (passed from url).

```
def show_reviews(request, username):
    latest_reviews = UserReview.objects.filter(name=username)
    context1 = {'latest_reviews': latest_reviews}
    return render(request, 'reviews.html', context1)
```

But whenever I go to the url attached to this view, I get the following error:

```
ValueError at /reviews/terminator/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'terminator'
```

If i change the query to UserReview.objects.all(), the page loads with no error and I can see all the reviews, so I'm guessing I made a simple mistake with filter(name=username) ?  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: is `name` a foreignkey ?

Comment: yes, name is a foreignkey

Comment: Could you post the UserReview model?

Comment: You need to lookup on the field for the username.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your `urls.py` it's hard to say for sure, but I'm guessing your URL pattern has something like:

```
url(r'^reviews/([\d]+)$', views.show_reviews),
```

when it needs to have something like:

```
url(r'^reviews/([\w]+)$', views.show_reviews),
```

or

```
url(r'^reviews/(.+)$', views.show_reviews),
```

Either that or your `UserReview` object's `name` field is an int when it should be a string. Perhaps post more of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `name` is a foreign key field and `username` is a string that comes from the URL pattern, which django is attempting to convert to a key (integer).  Instead of comparing username directly to the foreign key, follow that foreign key using `__` and check against the username there.

For example if `name` is a foreign key into Django's built-in User model (django.contrib.auth.models.User) you'd do it like this:

```
latest_reviews = UserReview.objects.filter(name__username=username)
```